# How do I use my self signed certificate in another computer?

Tags: excel, certificate, self-signed, excel-2016, vba

I created a self signed certificate in Windows 10 using New-SelfSignedCertificate function as below:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Subject "CN=VBA Code Signing" -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -Type CodeSigningCert
```

I exported the certificate including the private key and installed in another machine. However, the macro is still being blocked in the second machine. The macro settings is "Disable all macros except digitally signed macros"

Does anybody know why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: On the second computer by default the certificate probably shows as invalid or unable to validate.  You might be able to tell Windows to trust it anyway, I've never tried that.

Comment: Its not showing invalid or unable to validate. I was easily able to install it and see it in the certificate store.

Comment: Look at the details for the cert.  If it's self-signed there is no certificate chain and in details is where it might show as can't be validated or untrusted.

Comment: @Dave. Says the certificate is OK.

Comment: My guess then is that setting really means "... except digitally signed macros where the certificate is from a trsuted Certificate Authority like GoDaddy, Thawte or Digicert"

Comment: @Binit You installed the certificate in My (personal) store. Try to import the certificate to Trusted Root Certificates.

Comment: @Pepo I tried importing the certificate to Trusted Root Certificates. But still didn't work.

Comment: @Binit I would also try LocalMachine\Root store. Or enable [CAPI2 event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG0Yj.png). There should be information about validation process that has been done when validating macro signature.

Answer (score 0):

Office will only allow you to trust a self-signed certificate on the machine on which it was created.

You can use the `SELFCERT.EXE` application to quickly create a self signed certificate for office. The application is located here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\SELFCERT.EXE
```

Running `SELFCERT.EXE` shows the following dialog that states that the certificate is only trusted on the originating machine AND that a security warning is issued regardless:

[image: Running selfcert.exe shows this dialog]

It isn't mentioned in the documentation from Microsoft, that the certificate wont be trusted on the non originating machine, which is a shame. See [Digitally sign your VBA macro project](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/digitally-sign-your-vba-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01).